# Как обработать неопределенное кол-во полей в форме?

Tags: django

```
def index(request):
    form = EventCreate(request.POST)
    form.save()
    return redirect...
```

В request.POST приходит не определенное кол-во date_0, date_1... и time_0, time_1...

Есть модели

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...

class Date(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='dates')
```

и Есть форма

```
class EventCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    dates = ?
    ...

    def save(self):
        instance = super().save()
        for date in self.dates
            ...
```

Вопрос в том, как реализовать dates, нашел инфу про MultiValueField, но там не понятно, как работать с неопределенным кол-во полей

Comment: По моему, вам нужен FormSet

Comment: @Александр не понял о чем вы, можете по подробнее или кинуть ссылку на информацию об этом?

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/forms/formsets.html